# Linux CentOs: Setup ssh & sftp

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I have a desktop server which has CentOs 5. When im on the same LAN with the desktop server, i'm able to ssh but not when i tried to ssh from the public IP. How do i setup ssh and sftp for public IP??

The iptables result is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps 
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any 
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:smtp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:hosts2-ns 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:8140 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: You need to run the `sshd` daemon on your server side in order to be able to ssh to it. It should be easy to install. Configurating `sshd` is done in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as far as I know. Make sure your config allows listening on some port `n` which you use, and that it does listen to the right ip address.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a separate router that connects your LAN to the Internet, that router probably uses NAT, in which case you need to set up port forwarding for port 22 (hint: make the outside port something different to reduce the rate of attacks recorded in logs).

If this isn't the problem, consider updating your question with details of network arrangements.

Comment: I agree.  Since it's working on the same LAN and your SSH rule is from anywhere, it's not a problem with the local firewall.